# Upgrading from 4.6.4 to 4.6.8

Tags: upgrade

Problem in upgrade gives this warning.  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: CRM_Upgrade in /home/depot/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Service.php on line 131

Then trying to post events causes a json error.  Ideas?

Comment: Using Drupal 7.

Comment: did you get a 'successfully completed' page after the upgrade? after the status bar completes you should have seen that (you backed up your db,r right?)

Comment: Yes I did backup the database.  I think there was a write error on some of the files and I had to rerun it after to my chmods ??